# QML: How to convert Image Capture to Base64

Tags: qml, qt6

My qml app can capture a camera image and preview it but I need to convert the image to base64

I am compiling for MacOS using `Qt6.5`. I need to convert the image to `base64` so I can send the photo over `tcp`.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtMultimedia

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Convert QML Image to Base64"

    Camera
    {
        id:camera
        active: true
    }

    CaptureSession {
        camera: camera
        imageCapture : ImageCapture {
            id: imageCapture
            onImageCaptured: function(requestId, previewImage) {
                console.log("Image captured", requestId, previewImage);

                // Convert the captured image to Base64
                var base64String = Qt.btoa(imageCapture)
                console.log(base64String)

            }
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: photoPreview
        source: imageCapture.preview // always shows the last captured image
    }

    Button {
        id: takephoto
        text: "Take Photo"
        onClicked: imageCapture.capture()
    }

}
```

The console.log output is not encoded base64 image data instead its this:

> UVF1aWNrSW1hZ2VDYXB0dXJlKDB4NjAwMDAyZDU0NjAwKQ==

Which decoded is:

> QQuickImageCapture(0x600002d54600)

Comment: you probably should use `previewImage` which is `Image`, not the `imageCapture` which is `ImageCapture` type.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the only QML object capable of converting images to base64 is the canvas qml type. Unless someone wants to answer this question using c++ that would also be welcomed!!!

Here we capture an image where it gets loaded to photoPreview. When the user clicks the getBase64 button it prints out the working base64

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtMultimedia
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("encode qml image to base64")

    Rectangle
    {
        id: bgRect
        color: "white"
        anchors.fill: videoOutput
    }

    CaptureSession {
        imageCapture : ImageCapture {
            id: imageCapture
            onImageCaptured: {
               photoPreview.visible = true
            }
        }
        camera: Camera {
            id: camera
            active: true
        }

        videoOutput: videoOutput
    }
    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: imageCapture.capture();
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: photoPreview
        source: imageCapture.preview // always shows the last captured image
    }

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            ctx.drawImage(photoPreview, 0, 0, width, height);
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            console.log(dataUrl);
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: getBase64
        text: "Encode Base64"
        onClicked: {
            canvas.requestPaint()
            photoPreview.visible = false
        }
    }

    RoundButton {
        id: capture
        height: 45
        width: height
        text: ""
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: parent.height * 0.05
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        palette.button: "white"
        onClicked: imageCapture.capture()
    }

}
```